# No tests executed with grunt-qunit-junit

Tags: junit, gruntjs

I am following this guide to generate junit output from my js tests:

https://github.com/sbrandwoo/grunt-qunit-junit

I have installed grunt-qunit-junit into my local test project:

```
npm install grunt-contrib-qunit --save-dev
```

And this is my Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    "use:strict";
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        qunit_junit: {
            options: {

            },
            all: ["all_tests.html"]         
        },
    })  
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-qunit-junit');        
};
```

where `all_tests.html` is located in the same dir and lists all my *test.js files. But when I run:

```
user@ubuntu:~/Test$ grunt qunit_junit
Running "qunit_junit" task
>> XML reports will be written to _build/test-reports

Done, without errors.
```

Why are the tests not executed (the folder _build/test-reports is not created)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this plugin, but the README states that you should execute both the `qunit_junit` and `qunit` tasks: https://github.com/sbrandwoo/grunt-qunit-junit#usage-examples

Comment: That was it, I just needed to add `grunt.registerTask('test', ['qunit_junit', 'qunit']);`

Comment: Awesome :) Should I add my comment as an answer then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The README states that you should execute both the qunit_junit and qunit tasks: http://github.com/sbrandwoo/grunt-qunit-junit#usage-examples

For example: `grunt.registerTask('test', ['qunit_junit', 'qunit']);`